# has_one :through association Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a site which has members. Each member has a subscription. For a subscription a member needs to choose a plan of which there are 3.

Is this correct way to do the association

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :plan, :through => :subscription
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :member
    has_many :plans
end

class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :subscription
end
```

Then maybe something like this

```
member.plan
```

would be the plan a member is subscribed to.

Comment: Can a single subscription have more than one plans OR one of three plans?

Comment: Your associations seem inconsistent with your description. Your `has_many :plans` association on `Subscription` means that each subscription can have zero or more plans, with the foreign key stored in the plans table.If a subscription has one and only one plan, it should be a `belongs_to :plan`.

Comment: Each member can only have one plan. Should I change has_many :plans to has_one :plan. I want to have a way to create the plans in the admin area which is why I thought has_many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a member can belong to one plan at a time you can redo your models as follows:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :subscription
  has_one :plan, :through => :subscription
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :plan
end

class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscription
  has_many   :members    
end
```

Other solution is to avoid the `Subscription` model altogether by adding a `plan_id` column to `members` table.

```
# has a column called plan_id
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :plan
end

class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :members    
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the idea of not having the subscription model altogether so thank you.